# What's the gradient of $x^\intercal ab^\intercal x$?

Tags: vector-analysis, gradient-descent

I want to prove gradient $x^\intercal ab^\intercal x$ = $a^\intercal x b^\intercal + b^\intercal xa^\intercal$.
After attempts, I don't understand how to get "something+something" from a function which has no addition. Not sure if I am allowed to split it into two functions, and apply product rule.

Comment: The product rule is exactly how you get a sum from a function with no addition

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you, but i've tried this method, can't get the answer. They look similar, not the same.

Comment: What do you mean by “they look similar”? What do you end up getting? Perhaps you could edit your question to add the result of your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\l{\lambda}\def\n{\nabla}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3}}
$To avoid these kinds of transposition mistakes, I recommend the following approach.

Rewrite the objective function using the Frobenius product (see below),

then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= x^Tab^Tx \\&= ab^T:xx^T \\
d\phi
 &= ab^T:\LR{dx\,x^T+x\,dx^T} \\
 &= \LR{ab^T+ba^T}:\LR{dx\,x^T} \\
 &= \LR{ab^T+ba^T}x:dx \\
\grad{\phi}{x} &= \LR{ab^T+ba^T}x \\
\\
}$$

---

The Frobenius product is a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
This is also called the double-dot or double contraction product.

When applied to vectors $(n=\o)$ it reduces to the usual dot product.

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:AB &= CB^T:A = A^TC:B \\
}$$
As with the Hadamard product, the matrix on each side of the multiplication symbol $(:)$ must have *exactly* the same dimensions.